# Angular 4 inject <style> from src/style.scss last?

Tags: angular

In a standard Angular 4 project, it has the `style.css` (which I changed to `style.scss` in `.angular-cli.json`).

This is injected to the `<head>` of `index.html`.

Other components with their own styles gets injected after this.

How do I make it be injected last so that my global styles actually override those components' styles?

Reason being I've written styles there that override some vendor components that will be app wide.

Comment: easy fix is to use `!important` on style.css

Comment: Would any method work, Angular adds attribute tags to component styles, so their selectors are probably always going to be more specific than your global ones. Not sure if that applies to @Hareesh's idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important;` at the end of a css or scss line will force it to be #1 choice no matter what is called before or after it, as @Hareesh mentioned

This goes into about when it is appropriate to use.
https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Something you could also consider but I personally wouldnt recommend is removing the global style call and calling it after your own styles have been called